# Unable to locate tasks.json file to configure in VS Code when trying to run my HTML page in browser

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a basic html Page in VS code.

Expected: I want to see my code output in browser window opened within VS code

Actual : I was not able to see anything happening 
when I try to find the answers, it was mentioned to modify tasks.json file which I was not able to find anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

The reason why I was not able to find the tasks.json  file/workspace settings is I created the file in this way 
Open VS code>>file>>new>>save as html extension   -- Wrong way of creating a file

Actual way we should create the file is
Open VS code>>file>>Open folder>>(you  can create a folder and html file inside)>>file>>preference>>settings>>workspace setting(right corner this is enabled now)>>you can also type ctrl+shift+p and type "Configure Task Runner">>Other>>tasks.json(this is available now)

Conclusion -- You should create a working folder (workspace) to write or save files